# How to evaluate closed form for this sum $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{k\over [(pk)^2-1][(qk)^2-1]}?$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Observing Ramanujan [phi-function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RamanujanPhi-Function.html)

Given two examples

$${1\over 2}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{1\over (2k)^3-2k}=\ln 2\tag1$$

$$1+2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{1\over (3k)^3-3k}=\ln 3\tag2$$

Let the Ramanujan phi-function takes the general form of:

$$a+b\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{1\over (pk)^3-pk}=\ln x\tag3$$

$$c+d\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{1\over (qk)^3-qk}=\ln y\tag4$$

where $p<q$ and $p>1$

We would like to evaluate the closed form of this sum $(5)$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{k\over [(pk)^2-1][(qk)^2-1]}\tag5$$

Through much of our efforts we was able to came up with a sort of closed form but not sure for its correctness,

$$(5)={1\over q^2-p^2}\left({cq\over d}-{ap\over b}+\ln\left({x^{p/b}\over y^{q/d}}\right)\right)\tag6$$

**How do we work out the closed form for $(5)$?**

Comment: Multiply $(3)$ by $p/b$ and $(4)$ by $q/d$ and subtract resulting equations. You should get your desired equation. Like one of your previous question this one also appears to be a case of algebraic manipulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using partial fractions, exactly like you seem to have done. Another way of presenting the result is

Since by partial fractions
$${k\over [(pk)^2-1][(qk)^2-1]}=\frac{p}{q^2-p^2}{1\over pk[(pk)^2-1]}-\frac{q}{q^2-p^2}{1\over qk[(qk)^2-1]}$$

we can sum both sides and later make substitutions using $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{1\over pk[(pk)^2-1]}=\frac{\log x - a}{b}$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{1\over qk[(qk)^2-1]}=\frac{\log y-c}{d}$

Thus
$$\begin{align*} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{k\over [(pk)^2-1][(qk)^2-1]}&=\frac{p}{q^2-p^2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{1\over pk[(pk)^2-1]}-\frac{q}{q^2-p^2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{1\over qk[(qk)^2-1]}\\
&=\frac{1}{q^2-p^2} \left( \frac{p(\log x-a)}{b}-\frac{q(\log y-c)}{d}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{q^2-p^2}\frac{1}{bd}\left( (qcb-pad)+ (pd\log x-qb \log y) \right)
\end{align*}$$